# Entity framework: How to reduce database hits?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

So I have this query in my repository (also using Unit of Work pattern) which uses eager loading to make one hit to the database:

```
from g in _context.Games.Include(pg => pg.PreviousGame).Include(go => go.GameObjects)
where EntityFunctions.DiffMilliseconds(DateTime.Now, g.EndDate) > 0
    && g.GameTypeId == (int)GameTypes.Lottery
    && g.GameStatusId == (int)GameStatues.Open
select new LotteryModel
{
    EndDate = g.EndDate,
    GameId = g.Id,
    PreviousGameEndDate = g.PreviousGame.EndDate,
    PreviousGameId = g.PreviousGameId.HasValue ? g.PreviousGameId.Value : 0,
    PreviousGameStartDate = g.PreviousGame.StartDate,
    PreviousWinningObjectCount = g.PreviousGame.GameObjects.Select(go => go.Object.Count).FirstOrDefault(),
    PreviousWinningObjectExternalVideoId = g.PreviousGame.GameObjects.Select(go => go.Object.Video.ExternalVideoId).FirstOrDefault(),
    PreviousWinningObjectName = g.PreviousGame.GameObjects.Select(go => go.Object.Video.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
    StartDate = g.StartDate,
    WinningObjectCount = g.GameObjects.Select(go => go.Object.Count).FirstOrDefault(),
    WinningObjectExternalVideoId = g.GameObjects.Select(go => go.Object.Video.ExternalVideoId).FirstOrDefault(),
    WinningObjectName = g.GameObjects.Select(go => go.Object.Video.Name).FirstOrDefault()
};
```

However I'm reluctant to use this because I now have to create a separate LotteryModel object to return up throughout my other layers.

I would like to be able to return an entity of type "Game" which has all of the navigational methods to all of my other data (PreviousGame, GameObjects, etc) and then map the needed properties to my flat view model, but when I do this it seems to only lazy load the objects and then I have the additional hits to the DB.

Or do I have this wrong and whenever I need to return heirarchical data I should return it through my LINQ query in the select portion?

My basic goal is to reduce the hits to the DB.

Comment: Not a real answer to you question but when I have this kind of situations, I always go ahead and write a T-sql to create a view on my database. Then, I retrieve it back. This allows me to hit the database once and I can also create an index to my view. Complex queries make a mess on linq IMO.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. and I agree with you. I think I may either leave what I have because its only hitting the DB once.. or split the query into multiple quieries within a unit of work.. but I'm not sure if thats going to work because of the .Firsts() I  have..

Comment: Your query doesn't use eager loading. It uses projection. Eager loading doesn't project data to another class.

Comment: @Ladisalv Mrnka - isn't Include() eagar loading?

Comment: @Ryan - yes, but when you project, you lose the eager loading AFAIK

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand the problem.  You return your Games object and you can access the properties and subobjects off it.  Your use of the `Include()` method tells it to load what you need, and not lazy load it.

Make sure you return a single object via a .First, .FirstOrDefault, .Single, .SingleOrDefault, or similar methods.

Comment: Your answer lead to my eventual answer, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this query (FYI I'm using the System.Data.Objects namespace for the Include extension):

```
(from g in _context.Games.Include(pg => pg.PreviousGame.GameObjects.Select(o => o.Object.Video))
    .Include(go => go.GameObjects.Select(o => o.Object.Video))
where EntityFunctions.DiffMilliseconds(DateTime.Now, g.EndDate) > 0
    && g.GameTypeId == (int)GameTypes.Lottery
    && g.GameStatusId == (int)GameStatues.Open
select g).FirstOrDefault();
```

I guess I just needed to include more of the heirarchy and didn't know I could use Select() in the Include() function!